# Installing Windows 8.1 sideloaded app without powershell command

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

We have requirement to host LOB (Line of Business) app in an internal server (cannot upload it to Windows Store). Sideloading seems to be the way for it. However clients find it difficult to install by typing powershell commands. Is there any other way like download & install or double-tap install type of packaging for windows 8.1 apps?

Comment: Write an MSI that runs the powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 different solutions in my projects :

1. Create a custom MSI which run the powershell --> most common way
2. Use system center manager(http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2013/04/08/ways-to-deploy-modern-apps-for-windows-8-explained.aspx)
3. Use Intunes

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You might give a try to the Business Store: it uses the same principles of the Store but you own the content deployed on it:

https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/business-store/

Comment: It's only for Windows 10.